# How to suppress the strong initial value of the step function response

Tags: step-response, pid, damping

(Related to: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/14619)

**Quick question:** I am getting a strong initial value and strong undershoot in the step response. How can I suppress it with the feedback compensator?

[image: Step response]

**The context:** I am modelling the close loop response of a pizeo-electric actuator, having an extremely small damping factor $\xi \approx 0.01$ and high natural frequency $\omega_n = 250\,\text{Hz}$.

I wish to precisely control the actuator position and avoid oscillation. Also, I wish to increase the rise time of the step response to $T_r \geq 5\,\text{ms}$, and a settle time of $T_s \leq 60\,\text{ms}$. So, I followed [this article](https://doi.org/10.3389/fmech.2015.00014) to model a PI controller like the following:

```
Plant =

          1
----------------------
s^2 + 20 s + 2.468e+06

Controller=

s^2 + 6.4e+05
------------- x 2.0E3
      s
```

The PI controller has two zeros on the $j\omega$ axis, and one pole at the origin. I have control of the positions of the zeros, as well as the open loop Proportional gain.

[image: Root locus diagram]